# Write to random access file using superclass and extended class methods

Tags: java, inheritance, random-access

I have a Book class and a Library Book class which extends Book. I am storing the information in a random access file. I have a writeToFile method which writes Book objects to a random access file. My LibraryBook class's method writeToFile calls super.writeToFile and then I want it to write the fields specific to the LibraryBook to the file. What is the proper way to do this? see code:

method from the book class:

```
public void writeToFile(String fileName, long location) throws Exception {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile invFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
        // seek to correct record in file
        invFile.seek(location);
        // now write out the record
        // write out the data in fixed length fields
        // String fields must be truncated if too large
        // or padded with blanks if too small
                       //write out all Book variable to file
        invFile.writeLong(ISBN);
        //etc.....          

    } catch (FileNotFoundException notFound) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        throw io;
    }
}
```

method from the LibraryBook class which extends Book:

```
    public void writeToFile(String fileName, long location) throws Exception {
    try {
        super.writeToFile(fileName, location);
        RandomAccessFile invFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");

        // seek to correct record in file
        invFile.seek(location);
        // now write out the record
        // write out the data in fixed length fields
        // String fields must be truncated if too large
        // or padded with blanks if too small
                       //write library book variables to file
        invFile.writeLong(branchID);
                        //etc....

                    invFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException notFound) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        throw io;
    }
}
```

how can I code it so that the LibraryBook writeToFile method can call the superclass method and save a LibraryBook to the file?

Comment: Please can you shorten your code example to the minimum required... (see http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is essentially storing records into the file; there are many mechanisms already available for storing structured data into files. If you're interested in doing this for learning, then by all means keep going -- but if you just want this problem solved, look into using something like [SQLite3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite3) to provide your storage for you.

If you want to continue with this approach, you need to determine how much size each of your methods will use, allocate a portion of the file to each of the methods to update, and make sure that each one knows exactly where in the file is its location.

If this were just a C program, I'd suggest counting the fields each method is responsible for, `#define` those sizes and `#define` the offsets to add to `location` for each one.

But that doesn't feel very "Java" -- you're supposed to be able to modify parents, children, or add new classes entirely, without knowing details about the other classes.

So you might want to put one class in charge of writing structured data to files and query each of the classes involved for their data. Have each class return an array of `byte`s that they want written -- and have the one master class perform *all* the writing.

By consolidating all your file IO in one class, you can more easily change to another storage format later on, or maintain compatibility for two or three previous versions of your program, or provide multiple database backends to suit different needs at deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `writeToFile()` method final.

Then add a protected `writeExtraData()` method which does nothing in the case of a book, but is overridden to write the extra fields in the `LibraryBook` class. Call this from the middle of the `writeToFile()` method in `Book`. You will obviously need to implement a symmetric set of read methods.

Better yet, stop reinventing the wheel and writing nasty boilerplate code and just use the built-in `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` classes that the language provides to do this sort of thing. Then you can just go `readObject()`.